# Laravel Response Download returns a string

Tags: excel, laravel, laravel-5, response

As mentioned in the title, I'm generating an XLSX file and save it in to the public/reports/$filename. Excel file is generating pretty welli there is no issue here. The issue is once I tried to download it, it returns a string as follows:

```
// This generates the Excel file and save it to the disk and returns the file name
$report = Report::generateReport($request->type, $request->from, $request->to);

// This is the file path.
$filePath = public_path() . '/reports/' . $report;

return \response()->download($filePath, $report, [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    ]);
```

And the response that I get:

```
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
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: remove \`\\` before `response()`

Comment: look like its an base64 string ?

Comment: Try this syntax `Response::make($file_path, 200, [ 'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'])` and add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;`

Comment: Response facade only returns the file path, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by adding an extra AJAX get request to the file itself. Couldn't find another solution.